# Simple XML Element

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

I have been using a simple PHP wrapper to render a list of images from a very simple API.

The feed can be accessed at: http://feeds.feedburner.com/editappfeed?format=xml

The wrapper suddenly stopped working (which I am suspecting has something to do with a server upgrade by MT).

The hosting support is pointing me in the direction of cURL which I know little about and any attempts at using `SimpleXMLElement` result in:

> Call to undefined function: simplexmlelement()

My desired output is a list of titles and images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

–––

Full wrapper.

```
 $xml = SimpleXMLElement('http://feeds.feedburner.com/editappfeed/');

foreach ($xml->channel->children() as $i) {

   echo "<article class=''>", $i->description , "</article>";


}
```

Comment: could it be you just forgot the `new` before simplexmlelement? It's a class, not a function.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am afraid that this results in 

`Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: simplexmlelement in /nfs/c08/h01/mnt/116416/domains/blog.byed.it/html/index.php on line 24`

Comment: Are you sure SimpleXML is installed?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php .  It's not part of PHP by default, and if changes were made to the server, perhaps the module was uninstalled (PHP was installed from scratch but didn't install new module?).

Comment: @Sam that's incorrect: SimpleXml is enabled by default. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php - it might be that the provider disabled for some weird reason though.

Comment: Good point Sam. Have taken it up with MT. One thing they did indicate was that: 
_due to the enforcement by our administrators of remote url and file retrieval being disabled on the (gs) Grid-Service for security reasons._

Comment: @Nitzan remote url and file retrieval likely means they disabled the ini setting `url_allow_fopen`. That doesnt require disabling SimpleXml though. Also, it is completely pointless to disable `url_allow_fopen` but at the same time pointing you to/allowing the use of cURL.

Comment: Thanks — current MT response on Twitter http://l.byed.it/BIdB
Will update this thread as soon as I hear more.

Comment: change the ini setting as was suggested by MT via Twitter: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/793/Why+is+allow_url_fopen+disabled+on+the+%28gs%29+Grid-Service%3F Also, make sure you are actually running PHP5. SimpleXML wasnt available before that. You can check with `var_dump(extension_loaded('SimpleXML'));` and `phpversion()`

Comment: @Gordon Looks like I stand corrected.  Still...  The error seems to indicate that the class isn't defined.  What version of PHP is currently installed?  Looks like you have to have 1.) PHP5, 2.) libxml PHP extension must be installed with --enable-libxml (default), 3.) before PHP 5.1.2 must have --enable-simplexml enabled.

Comment: @Gordon — I would changed it but I am not sure what security implications that it have on the server (across multiple domains).

Comment: @sam — I am running PHP5 as of 10 minutes ago, it seems to have reverted on a couple domains.
I will definitely enquire with MT about 2/3, although here's a new response: https://twitter.com/#!/mediatemple/status/129287422382063617

Comment: None, unless your users are careless enough to not sanitize input they fetched from remote locations. On a sidenote, even with `allow_url_fopen` enabled, you are not calling the class correctly. If you want to fetch urls with SimpleXmlElement you'd have to use `new SimpleXmlElement($url,0,true)` to indicate that it is a URL and not raw XML. The alternative would be to use `simplexml_load_file($url)` instead.

Comment: @gordon — problem solved.
It was `new SimpleXmlElement($url,0,true) ;` that cracked it

Comment: Sam  / Gordon – thanks for your help. Can I credit your help on GitHub? https://github.com/nitzan/EditAppSimpleWrapper

Comment: @Nitzan no need for that. You are welcome.

Comment: @Gordon I think Gordon solved it for you.  Gordon - you should post the answer below so you can get credited for it.  Glad I could help Nitzan.

Answer (score 2):

Summary from my comments above:

You have to use `new SimpleXmlElement($url,0,true)` to load remote data.

Also, [change the ini setting for `allow_url_fopen`](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/793/Why+is+allow_url_fopen+disabled+on+the+%28gs%29+Grid-Service?) as was suggested by MT via Twitter and make sure you are actually running PHP5. You can check with `var_dump(extension_loaded('SimpleXML'));` and `phpversion()`.